# Why my clearcase views are often stopped?

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We recently upgraded to Clearcase version 8.0.1.8 . In recent days our Clearcase dynamic views are often stopped. Since my views were used in Jenkins if they stopped , some user are calling me and say build is not working.

The root cause is Clearcase view is stopped. How to avoid this ? Or is there any way to start my view every time via Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is force Jenkins to start the view it needs to use. This can be done with the "[cleartool startview](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_startview.htm)" command. You just need to specify the view tag you want to start at the beginning of the job that needs to use the view, e.g.,

```
cleartool startview <view-tag>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a Jenkins side-effect on dynamic view but:

- you can check the logs (of the client and the view server) to see if there are any events explaining why the view stops
- you can add a first build step in the job which ensures that the view is started.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to 8.x from a really old version, you may be dealing with the view idle timeout. If a view server process is idle for 2 hours,  it shuts down. It's also possible that someone is shutting down the view. I had someone recently set up a job that 1) ran in parallel on multiple systems; 2) started and set a specific (shared) view; 3) ran a short job; and 4) ran a cleartext endview -server. This tended to do interesting things to the other hosts.

Generally, this just increases the amount of time the job takes as the MVFS will eventually restart the view.

If, OTOH, the I views are getting ended on the client so they drop off /view, that's a little different. I'd set up ClearCase command history and see who is stopping the views.